# Growl Notifications for Stack Exchange websites?

Tags: notifications

I'm looking for a way to get Growl notifications for new questions on the Stack Exchange websites, matching some pre-defined tags.

I've tried [SENotify](https://stackapps.com/questions/817/senotify-stack-exchange-new-question-notification-perl-growl), but it didn't work for me. Any alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get Stack Exchange Growl notifications using [Adium](http://adium.im/) + [Stackguru](https://stackapps.com/questions/345/stackguru-a-jabber-bot-for-all-stackapps-sites).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Apparently they've just fixed SENotify - which now works for me -, but I've also tried yours and it works like a charme.

Answer (score 3):

[RSS Growler](http://osiris.laya.com/projects/RSSGrowler/) + feeds?

Comment: I tried that. Works perfectly with other feeds, not with the ones from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look to [Newt](https://stackapps.com/questions/1993/newt-question-answer-and-comment-and-rep-change-notifications-for-os-x) on [StackApps](http://stackapps.com), I'm currently using it and it's a pretty neat and solid app.